# IBM Watson Speech-to-Text speech-javascript-sdk "HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available"

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-speech

I'm trying to set up IBM Watson Speech-to-Text to run in my Angular frontend. I'm using German Attanasio's [speech-javascript-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk) library. I want the transcript text to go to the console so I'm using the [microphone-streaming-object-to-console.html](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/examples/static/microphone-streaming-object-to-console.html) example. Here's my code:

```js
const options = {
      token: $scope.token,
      model: 'en-US_BroadbandModel',
      word_confidence: true,
      object_mode: true
};

var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone(options);
```

The error I'm getting is

```
watson-speech.js:10482 WebSocket connection to 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&watson-token=[object%20Object]' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
```

My guess is that my token isn't in the right format. The IAM bearer token is provided as a JSON object:

```js
{
   access_token: "eyJraWQiOiIyMDIwMDIyNTE4MjgiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.e…", 
   expiration: 1585264266, 
   expires_in: 3600, 
   refresh_token: "OKA5toCaoVmYsPbwpjARE1971xspAe7Xg5nOm9pRrLKjKgaubr…", 
   scope: "ibm openid",
}
```

I tried providing the bare naked access_token, and I tried providing the JSON object. Both resulted in the same error message. Which format is correct?

Did I set up the `options` object correctly? Is it `object_mode` or`objectMode`?

I don't understand what `Object.assign(token,` means in the example code.

Comment: I recommend asking here as well: http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/

Comment: The repo has the server-side examples. Are you using one of them to generate the token?

Comment: data_henrik, I have a Firebase Cloud Function that generates the token and a listener in the browser that gets the new token.

Comment: My latest novel, er, [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891348/ibm-cloud-speech-to-text-sdk-auth-failures-with-bearer-token) also answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the solution working perfectly:

In 'options' constant you need to change the field '**token**' by '**accessToken**' and It should be works.

NOTE:

The field 'model' in 'options' has a default value, but if you want to change it you have to set value to 'model' and 'laguage',

```
const params = {
        accessToken: 'token'
        format: true,           
        extractResults: true,
        objectMode: true,
        model:'es-MX_BroadbandModel',
        laguage: 'es-MX'
      };
```