# IBM Cloud Speech-to-Text SDK auth failures with bearer token

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-speech

I'm learning to use the [Watson Speech JS SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk). In particular I like [Transcribe from Microphone, with Alternatives](https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/microphone-word-confidence.html). I'm generating my token with a Firebase Cloud Function. I'm using AngularJS, not JQuery. The first problem I'm running into is

```js
var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone(Object.assign(token, {
          objectMode: true,
          format: false,
          wordConfidence: true
}));
```

I got this error message:

```
WatsonSpeechToText: missing required parameter: opts.token
```

(Using `$scope.token` or `token` makes no difference.)

Looking up this error in the [documentation](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/speech-javascript-sdk/master/speech-to-text_recognize-microphone.js.html):

```js
module.exports = function recognizeMicrophone(options) {
  if (!options || !options.token) {
    throw new Error('WatsonSpeechToText: missing required parameter: opts.token');
  }
```

OK, it's looking for an `options` object. I fixed the error with this code:

```js
const options = {
      token: $scope.token,
      objectMode: true,
      format: false,
      wordConfidence: true
};
console.log(options);
var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone(options);
```

Now I get this error:

```js
WebSocket connection to 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&watson-token=[object%20Object]' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
```

The `options` object logs this:

```js
token:
  access_token: "eyJraWQiOiIyMDIwMDIyNTE4MjgiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYW1faWQiOiJp0tU2..."
  expiration: 1585332575
  expires_in: 3600
  refresh_token: "OKC8z8ebLMzZcrAt6YgInnJJn0UIx1P3NTeDvdEC3kJqIQ7Yn9J9iu6-DF..."
  scope: "ibm openid"
  token_type: "Bearer"
objectMode: true
format: false
wordConfidence: true
smart_formatting: false
```

The token is a JSON object, which includes the `access_token`. Is this what the SDK wants? The [RecognizeStream documentation](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/speech-javascript-sdk/master/RecognizeStream.html) doesn't say whether it wants the JSON token or just the naked `access_token`.

Adding `000` to the `expiration` field shows that I have 53 minutes left on this token.

I'm using the API key that's specific to my Speech-to-Text service.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version [0.37.0](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of the SDK introduced breaking changes:

```
All options parameters for all methods are coverted to be lowerCamelCase
For example: access_token is now accessToken and content-type is now contentType
```

This is related to IBM's move from Cloud Foundry services with username/password auth to Services with IAM auth and api keys. The [SDK documentation](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/docs/README.md) says:

```
NOTE: The token parameter only works for CF instances of services. For RC services using IAM for authentication, the accessToken parameter must be used.
```

The `options` object looks like this if you use an api key:

```js
const options = {
      accessToken: $scope.token,
      objectMode: true,
      format: false,
      wordConfidence: true
};
```

If you leave out the token property you get this error message:

```
WatsonSpeechToText: missing required parameter: opts.token (CF) or opts.accessToken (RC)
```

What that means is, if you're getting your token from Cloud Foundry (CF) the property must be `opts.token` (or `options.token`); but if you're getting your token from IAM auth and an api-key, which is called `RC` for no reason I know of, then the property must be `opts.accessToken` (or `options.accessToken`).

Confusing the matter, the [demo source code](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/examples/static/microphone-word-confidence.html) implies that `access_token` is the property name:

```js
var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone(Object.assign(token, {
          objectMode: true,
          format: false,
          wordConfidence: true
}));
```

`Object.assign` is taking the `target` token object as it comes from IBM and then adding or replacing the properties and values in the `source` object. Because the property is `access_token` in the IAM token you'd think that, because the demo runs, `access_token` is the property. But apparently the demo is running on a Cloud Foundry token, which can use either `token` or `access_token` as the property name.

If you get this error message:

```
WatsonSpeechToText: missing required parameter: opts.token (CF) or opts.accessToken (RC)
```

then you're using neither `token` nor `accessToken` as the property name.

If you get this error message:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&watson-token=[object%20Object]' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
```

then you're using `token` with a token generated with an IAM api-key. Or your token is expired. You can check that easily by putting this code in your app to tell you how many minutes are left on your token:

```js
// shows time to token expiration
    var expiry = new Date($scope.token.expiration * 1000);
    var now = Date.now();
    var duration = -(now - expiry);

    function msToTime(duration) {
      var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
      seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
      minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
      hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

      hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
      minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      return "Token expires in " + minutes + ":" + seconds + " minutes:seconds";
    }
    console.log(msToTime(duration))
```

You can test if your token is valid from the CLI. First get a new token:

```
curl -k -X POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" \
  --data-urlencode "apikey=s00pers3cret" \
  "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token"
```

then request the language models:

```
curl -X GET "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/models?access_token=eyJraWQiO...."
```

I had another problem in my code. I was updating the [IBM Speech-to-Text SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/releases) but my code was linking to an old SDK I'd installed with bower three years ago. I didn't realize that I was using 0.33.1 when 0.38.0 is the latest version. Add this to your code to catch this problem:

```js
console.log (WatsonSpeech.version);
```

With the old SDK I was getting an old error message that didn't even mention the new property name:

```
WatsonSpeechToText: missing required parameter: opts.token
```

My [blog post](https://medium.com/@tdkehoe/ibm-cloud-speech-to-text-two-implementations-1ce0e617a519) has more about IBM Cloud Speech-to-Text.